# Getting unpermitted parameter using collection_select with multiple => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collection-select

[image: Console and the view]

I have two models with no associations between them. I am fetching the list of names as options for selection to the primary model. Collection_select without multiple => true works  as expected. But when i add multiple i get the unpermitted parameter error.

Comment: Can you try replacing `f.collection_select(:conf, Container.all, ...)` with 

`f.collection_select(:conf[], Container.all, ...)`? Does this work?

Comment: @Aakanksha, im getting the wrong number of attributes error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `:conf_string` is an array, so you need to permit it as an array.

In your `BaseTablesController`:

```
def base_table_params
  params.require(:base_table).permit(:name, conf_string: [])
end
```

Don't forget to update `:conF_string` to `:conf_string`. I think you made a typing mistake

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working now. But i have a doubt, can i make multiple selection return binary values on selection. for example the selected options return 1 others return 0. So the value inserted to the database will be of format "101101" string.

Comment: Using `unpack(B*)`, ie: `'1'.unpack('B*') # => ["00110001"]`